# Why is the session null in a method inside controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, session, c#-4.0, session-variables

I am creating a MVC 5 application. Which grabs a array of objects as json then i deserialize it create a new object and then i store the object in session. I can access the session in the partial view and it is working fine but when i click in a link on that page it direct me to a method in the same controller and i try to retrieve the session but it is null. Anyone has any idea why is this happening.
i store it in a method in controller like this and return view , driver is an object

```
HttpContext.Session["allInfo"] = driver;

HttpContext.Session["loggedIn"] = true;
```

Then i check it in a partial view and create dynamic links. it is working fine till here i get loggedIn as true and allInfo is not null

```
@if (HttpContext.Current.Session["loggedIn"] != null)
{
    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Other Links", "Index", "Home")</li>
    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Other Links", "About", "Home")</li>
    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Other Links", "Contact", "Home")</li>

}
```

A link in the page will navigate user to different view. In the controller i try to retrieve the session but it is null now. Why is this happening???

```
driver = (Driver) HttpContext.Session["allInfo"];
```

Comment: First off you can use Session object directly in the controller instead of using `HttpContext.Session`. I don't see any wrong with your code. What kind of session storage are you using? What is the expiration of your session?

Comment: So after saving in session it will return  Index page of Client and another link would take them to other page which will show this list of objects. I skipped the index page and redirected to the list of object page, At this point the session works. But there are several sorting and adding links  which will again try to retrieve the same session but now  i get NULL again. This is so weird. Any idea??

Comment: Is it possible that the session gets cleared in-between? Are you using `Session.RemoveAll()` or `Session.Abandon()` anywhere?

Comment: I don't have that anywhere. But am sure something like that is happening .in the background but I don't know where. When I call a session then it's a new instances of session